# Deploying multiple flask apps on aws-ec2 with gunicorn + nginx

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, flask, amazon-ec2, gunicorn

I am trying to deploy multiple Flask applications in a AWS EC2 without success :(.

I'm following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@prithvishetty/deploying-multiple-python-3-flask-apps-to-aws-using-nginx-d78e9477f96d), the steps seems to be simple enough, however I haven't managed to make it work. This is my configuration:

- Intance type t2.micro
- OS Ubuntu, 22.04 LTS, 64-bit
- Security group configuration: open the ports 80, 8000 and 8080 (source 0.0.0.0/0 which I understand is "everyone") and pointed the inbound traffic (port 22) directly to my IP address.
- Directory structure:
  [Directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/womXS.png)
- Ngingx, Gunicorn and Flask have been all installed globally in the instance.
- app_one gunicorn service configuration:

```
[Unit]
Description=Gunicorn instance for app_one
After=network.target
[Service]
User=ubuntu
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/app_one
ExecStart=/usr/bin/gunicorn3 --workers 2 --bind unix:flaskapp.sock -m 007 app:app
Restart=always
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

- app_two gunicorn service configuration:

```
[Unit]
Description=Gunicorn instance for app_two
After=network.target
[Service]
User=ubuntu
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/app_two
ExecStart=/usr/bin/gunicorn3 --workers 2 --bind unix:flaskapp.sock -m 007 app:app
Restart=always
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

- nginx default enabled file deleted and replaced with this "flaskapp" file:

```
server{
    listen 80;
    server_name 3.89.19.163;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/app_one/flaskapp.sock;
        error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.3.89.19.163;
    }
}

server{
    listen 8080;
    server_name 3.89.19.163;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/app_two/flaskapp.sock;
        error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.3.89.19.163;
    }
}
```

- nginx.conf:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;

        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
        # gzip_comp_level 6;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#       # See sample authentication script at:
#       # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
#
#       # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#       # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#       # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
#
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:110;
#               protocol   pop3;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
#
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:143;
#               protocol   imap;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
#}
```

- and last  /var/log/nginx/error.log

```
2023/10/02 09:17:31 [notice] 2788#2788: using inherited sockets from "6;7;"
```

As far as I know, this error file shows an update and since is a "notice" I have nothing to worry about, however, looks like there is something odd in my configurations file because when I ran
curl localhost:80 or curl localhost:8080 I get a "502 Bad Gateway"

and when I visit my publicIP address (publicIP, publicIP:80, publicIP:8080) this is what I get:
[ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xEFzF.png)

Any help is going to be very much appreciated, thanks in advance